# Playwright - using the await.goto() function sometimes the game I'm running stops before entering the screen

Tags: javascript, automation, playwright

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('game spin', async ({ page }) => {

  await page.goto('https://gpas-games-trtgpasdev01.extdev.eu/games/StarsAblaze/last/game/index.html#clientType=casino&clientPlatform=web&username=User15&password=Pass123456&casino=playtech85001&locale=en&real=1&historyurl=http%3A%2F%2Fbbc.co.uk&cashierurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bgo.com%2Fcashier%3Fmode%3Ddeposit%26clienttype%3Dcasino&backurl=http%3A%2F%2Fashgaming.com&minimumSpinTime=0&crosslaunchurl=http%3A%2F%2Fbbc.co.uk');
  
await page.waitForTimeout(10000);

  //await page.pause();

});
```

I'm trying to do a load game test script, but it cuts out before I get to the game.

I'm expecting the game to load and, after it has appeared fully on the screen, to stop the script.

I did the await page.waitForTimeout(10000); or looking for an equivalent to making the game load sleep after 40 seconds.